# Multiple python scripts edit txt file

Tags: python

I am developing an app, in which two scripts have access to single txt file. The first script should be writing some data (each in new line) every minute or so, and the second one would read this data, work with it and after that delete it or edit the line. What would happened if first script writes new data and at the same time second script edits some other data in the file. I think there would be some kind of collision, which I can’t afford to have.

How to overcome this problem

Comment: why txt file and not db like sqlite3?

Comment: Trying to have two processes read **and write** to a file like this is a recipe for complications. If you need your two scripts to communicate with each other, use a database like sqlite, set up a socket or pipe between them and use that, or use a messaging library like zeromq, or a service like redis. What you're trying isn't impossible, but it does require carefully planning out your semantics and correctly setting up synchronization via file locking.

Comment: This looks very much like XY problem

Comment: Have you been set this task as homework? If so, please have a look at [homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). If no, please change your question to explain what problem you are trying to solve with that solution, so that people can suggest better ways to solve it.